# Transformar resposta em comentário

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica, comentários

Estou trabalhando na fila de analise e tenho visto que algumas respostas (geralmente sinalizadas como de pouca qualidade) são perguntas sobre a questão em si (ex: você testou em `X tecnologia` ou em `Y lugar`) logo tenho recomendado exclusão, porem esta não é minha intenção, gostaria de as transformar em um comentário, isso é possível? detalhe esta `pergunta` tem comentários nela.

A pergunta é esta: [Site com áudio MP3 não toca no iPhone](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65807/site-com-%C3%A1udio-mp3-n%C3%A3o-toca-no-iphone) porém a referida resposta foi excuida, mas ela seguia o padrão do exemplo.

Comment: falta o link da pergunta...

Comment: O título não seria transformar resposta em comentário? Moderadores tem esse privilégio.

Comment: @rray erro meu, corrigido.

Answer (score 6):

Sempre que encontrar uma resposta que não é uma resposta, adicione uma flag para a moderação. Os moderadores podem transformar a resposta em um comentário se concordarem com situação.

Isso é particularmente comum com quem ainda não tem pontuação o suficiente para comentar em questões de outros usuários.

Comment: Para garantir que vejamos a sinalização, é melhor sinalizar como "outro" e explicar que é caso de conversão (ver minha resposta).

Answer (score 3):

O fato é que o sistema não ajuda, o caminho que levaria à conversão em comentário não é prioritário no fluxo de tratamento das sinalizações e análises. Vejamos:

- A maioria das sinalizações nem habilita o botão de converter em comentário na fila de flags dos moderadores. Não tenho certeza, mas acho que apenas "não é uma resposta" habilita. Claro que temos como converter qualquer resposta em comentário, mas o botão na fila é uma mão na roda.
- Não existe como os usuários indicarem que a resposta deve ser convertida, a não ser sinalizando como "outro..." e escrevendo o motivo (o que não habilita o tal botão para os moderadores).
- Muitas das sinalizações como "não é uma resposta" nem chegam na fila dos moderadores, pois são resolvidas pela comunidade na fila de análise (quando a análise tem uma decisão unânime em até uma hora).

Não sei se isso é intencional ou não – já que comentários são considerados pouco importantes. Mas eu acho importante que houvesse mais caminhos que facilitassem a conversão em comentário.

Comment: .@bfavaretto estou agora seguindo as orientações do @utluiz e fazendo da seguinte forma: as que não agregam nenhum valor eu recomendo a exclusão as respostas "tons de cinza" (não é uma resposta boa mas traz um norte ao autor da pergunta) eu recomendo a exclusão na area de analise e vou na resposta e sinalizo para um moderador e explico o motivo.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Ótimo, por enquanto é o jeito de garantir que a gente veja. Espero que isso melhore um dia.